# While-loop breaks, and I don't know the reason why

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop, codeblocks

I was writing a code for a counter. If I give 'a' as input, it should +1 the counter and show it on the screen. But when I do it, it shows 1 on the screen and the program ends. I want it to run until and unless i give some other character as input. What's the mistake I am making?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Counter = 0;
    char t;

    while(true)
    {
        t = cin.get();
        if(t == 97)
        {
            Counter = Counter + 1;
        }
        else
            break;
        system("cls");
        cout << Counter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably getting a `'\n'` character after the first iteration.

Comment: I'm guessing you're hitting return after "a". So the next character will be the end-of-line character.

Comment: You should write `'a'` instead of `97` in your code, as it is much more intelligible to those who have not memorized the ASCII table.

Comment: Don't understand the down votes though. Question is asked correctly. Shows the problem and describes what is intended.

Comment: It's working if I use "cin >> t;" instead of "t = cin.get();"

Is there any way I don't have to press "Return/Enter" key  to take an input?

Just keep pressing "a" and it should keep on going until I press some other key.

Comment: Tip for finding the solution yourself: Add a putchar() (or whatever the wicked name in ``std::cout`` might be) to see what you were getting. Either all the time or simply at the times where you call ``break``.

Comment: @Manan Singh consider not using iostream and simply getchar() or getch() or getche() :)

Comment: @bittickler, I am using C++11 with MinGW compiler, it doesn't have console input/output header which contains all those features.

Comment: @MananSingh I am sure MinGW also allows to write: ``#include <cstdio>``

Comment: @BitTickler `getchar()` would have the same "problem" and the other things are non-standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Counter = 0;
    char t;

    while(true)
    {
        t = cin.get();
        if(t == 97)
        {
            Counter = Counter + 1;
        }
       // else
        //    break;
        system("cls");
        cout << Counter;
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Your `else break;` is the reason why you're closing after any interation. Basically after any iteration, it will break because due to any non-`a` input. However, running the code above, you will see the counter increment at every `a` input given and it will not break.

This will give you the basic operation you're looking for which is increment the counter based on input a, otherwise do nothing.

**Edit:** The above code will buffer your input and read it all, so if you have 5  `a`'s like the following `aaaaa`, it will read it and output 5 for the counter.

**If you want to break out of the loop, i suggest this:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Counter = 0;
    char t;

    while(true)
    {
        cin >> t;
       // t = cin.get();
        if(t == 97)
        {
            Counter = Counter + 1;
        }
        else
          break;
        system("cls");
        cout << Counter;
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it and it works. Seems to be with how `cin.get()` reads the buffered input from the console (i think). Not too sure on the specifics, but `cin >> t` does the trick.

**Edit 2:** Did some reading and i think `cin.get()` will consume the next character after your input, but in this case it is a newspace `\n`, which is why it will always break in your original code.

Comment: How would you break out of the loop in this case?

Comment: @JeffS Updated answer to reflect breaking out of loop.

Comment: I already figured out the Edit 1. And Thank you for clearing my doubt, the first part was really helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

The issue is when you are entering your `'a'`, you are probably hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well, which is interpreted as another `char`. That second `char` is definitely not `a`, so your program breaks. This can be verified by just outputting what you read:

```
for (;;) {
    std::cout << '?';
    char t = std::cin.get();
    std::cout << (int)t << '\n';
    if (t != 'a') break;
}
std::cout << "done\n";
```

Which, when run, prints:

```
?a
97   // this is 'a'
?10  // this is '\n', note the additional ?
done
```

The simplest fix would be to use the input stream operator on `cin`, which would discard whitespace in the input (whereas `get()` does not):

```
char t;
for (;;) {
    std::cout << '?';
    std::cin >> t;
    std::cout << (int)t << '\n';
    if (t != 'a') break;
}
std::cout << "done\n";
```

Which, when run, produces:

```
?a
97 
?b
98 
done
```

which is what you'd intended.

Comment: `cin >> t` discards whitespace, there is no "interpret as end-of-previous-input" (whatever that means). The previous input was ended by virtue of the fact that one character was read.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Just as a matter of (related) interest: Does the standard define how consoles are supposed to work? Imagine, one implementation sends each input character individually vs another implementation which is in line buffered mode and only sends when enter is hit. I never really got, where the abstraction is done iostream is relying on.

Comment: @BitTickler: Are you referring to the standard on console integration to the environment? As far as visual studio is concerned, it buffers all inputs until enter is pressed. I have not seen any "polling" from the environment to the console. But that may just be due exposure (or lack there of).

Comment: @Javia1492 Indeed - I noticed differences between different "types" of consoles. Be it a networked console or a unix console or a windows console. This is why I wonder how istream::get() and istream::getline() can guarantee to behave the same way in all situations.